# HTML5 form with jQuery doesn't work on Chrome and Opera

Tags: php, ajax, html, jquery

I've used the exact files from this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/
The ideea is to submit the form without refreshing, and displaying a nice animation after submission.
But when I try to use the files for my personalised form, the animation doesn't work on Chrome and Opera. Why?

```
<div id="contact_form">
    <form name="contact" method="post" action="">
        <p>Hi, my name is</p>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input" size="20" value="" class="text-input" />

        <p> and my email is</p> 
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input" size="20" value="" class="text-input"/> 

        <p>More Random Text.</p> 
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="input" onfocus="this.value='';" class="text-input"> ... </textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your actual implementation.  The example on the page seems to work fine on Chrome.

Comment: Indeed, the example works fine.

Comment: So seems like it would be a problem with your personalized form.  So, we can't help without seeing your code changes.

Comment: There it is. So it works on Safari and Firefox, but not on Chrome and Opera.

Comment: That's the html, what about the javascript?  Can you reproduce the problem at http://http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I didn't make almost any changes to the javascript. Just changed the "phone" variable to "message". It doesn't work on jsfiddle either.

Comment: Great, can you post a link to the fiddle so we can figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works ok in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CTGa3/2/

Works in Firefox and Chrome.  I am not using your php because I don't have access to it.  Instead, I am doing a dummy ajax call via jsfiddle, but the result should be the same.

The only thing I could see is that you didn't include the code for `runOnLoad`.  If you include the code, or remove the `runOnLoad()` call, everything works fine.  That piece of code is outdated anyway, because jQuery can do that for us.  You just have to move this line:

```
$("input#name").select().focus();
```

To the top of your jQuery code block:

http://jsfiddle.net/CTGa3/3/

Comment: Or it may be because I didn't edit the process.php file? I don't know anything about php so I just left it as it was. Might sound stupid.

Comment: Of course you will need to update the php.  Where do you expect your form info to go if you don't make sure the php is mailing it to your email address?  The php is also looking for `name`, `email`, and `phone`.  You changed the form to do `message` instead.  You would need to modify it for that.